# nodemailer not sending email on server?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, nodemailer

So i have created a form with a react front end and a node js and nodemailer backend. I am trying to send that data in an email. I can send it to the back end at that is received perfectly fine however, I am getting an issue when sending out the emaiil as the 'mail not sent' error is getting executed from the Transporter.sendMail function and I'm not to sure why.

Would love to get some help. Please see the code below for my server. I have obviously removed my authentication details for security purposes.

console log error:

[0] not sent

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const path = require('path');
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const port = 5000;
const cors = require("cors");
app.use(cors());
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // to support JSON-encoded bodies
app.use(
  bodyParser.urlencoded({
    // to support URL-encoded bodies
    extended: true
  })
);

const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'gmail',
  auth: {
    user: 'email',
    pass: 'password',

  }
});




app.get("/home", (req, res) => {
    console.log("Hello from .get /home", req.body.generalDetails, req.body.firstName, req.body.mName );

})






app.post("/home", (req, res) => {

  var mailOptions = {
                from: 'email',
                to: 'email',
                subject: 'Hello',
                text: req.body.generalDetails,

            }

            transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(err, res) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log('Mail not sent');
                } else {
                    console.log('Mail sent');
                }
            });

  let data = [{
    //page one data
    generalDetails: req.body.generalDetails,
    fName: req.body.fName,
    mName: req.body.mName,
    lName: req.body.lName,
    email: req.body.email,

   }];

   res.json(data);
 }

);



app.listen(port, () => `Server running on port ${port}`);
```

Comment: did u configure your gmail to allow less secure apps to use your gmail

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to modify some snippets in your code as below:

```js
const smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: "Gmail", // <======
  auth: {
    user: YOUR_GMAIL_ADDRESS,
    pass: YOUR_GMAIL_PASSWORD
  }
});
...
let mailOptions = {
  from: FROM_ADDRESS,
  to: TARGET_MAIL_ADDRESS,
  subject: 'Hello',
  text: req.body.generalDetails,
  html: req.body.generalDetails, // <======
};
smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, function (err) {
  if (err) {
    // failed
  } else {
    // sent
  }
});
...
```

PS: why don't you share the error log if it still goes on?

Comment: Hey, so I used that code and I am still getting an error from the smpt transport.sendmail function. I have just logged the else statement to 'not sent'

 [nodemon] starting `node server.js`
[0] not sent

Comment: @TomHunt would you please update your question with that error console log?